# How to Post Json Data In Servlet?

Tags: java, json, servlet-3.0

I have a json data which can be something like:

```
1st json data   
[
  {
    "id_form_delegate": "1",
    "nama_merchant": "MATAHARI BARU SERASI",
    "kota_merchant": "BALI",
    "alamat_merchant": "JL PAKUBUWONO 2D",
    "province_merchant": "BALI",
    "mid_merchant": [
      "112000902755",
      "112000902754"
    ],
    "tid_merchant": [
      "2431002547",
      "2531016215"
    ]
  }
]
```

or something like

```
2nd json data
[
  {
    "id_form_delegate": "1",
    "nama_merchant": "MATAHARI BARU SERASI",
    "kota_merchant": "BALI",
    "alamat_merchant": "JL PAKUBUWONO 2D",
    "province_merchant": "BALI",
    "mid_merchant": "112000902755",
    "tid_merchant": "2431002547"
  }
]
```

This my servlet code

```
JSONArray arrMid = jsonObject.getJSONArray("mid_merchant");
 mid = new String[arrMid.size()];
 JSONArray arrTid = jsonObject.getJSONArray("tid_merchant");
 tid = new String[arrTid.size()];

//            
                System.out.println("nama_merchant: " + nama_merchant);
                System.out.println("kota_merchant: " + kota_merchant);
                System.out.println("alamat_merchant: " + alamat_merchant);
                System.out.println("province_merchant: " + province_merchant);
                System.out.println("mid: " + mid.length);
                System.out.println("tid: " + tid.length);
```

if post 1st data result success, but if I post 2nd data I've Got error

this my error logs

> net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["mid_merchant"] is not a
>   JSONArray. net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["tid_merchant"] is
>   not a JSONArray.

how to get value mid_merchant.length & tid_merchant.length using JSONArray

Thanks

Comment: You get the error, because both values are strings and not arrays for the 2nd example. Check for the type before accessing the contents and treating them as an array.

Comment: i have not tried this code but pass that value in this way :  "mid_merchant": ["112000902755"].may be help to you.

Comment: if post 1st data value "mid_merchant": [ "112000902755", "112000902754" ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method `get(String field)` and check type of result:

```
Object node = jsonObject.get("mid_merchant");

String[] mid;
if (node instanceof JSONArray) {
   mid = new String[((JSONArray) node).size()];
} else {
   mid = new String[1];
}
```

or one-liner:

```
String[] mid = new String[node instanceof JSONArray ? ((JSONArray) node).size() : 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that mid_merchant isn't an array in the second case, so you can't use JSONArray to get it's length because it has no length, it's just a String. You could send an array with only one value:

```
"mid_merchant": ["112000902755"],
```

or, if that's not what you want, you can check if it is an array (or even capture that exception) and get the String value with the getString method if it's not an array:

```
String stringMid = jsonObject.getString("mid_merchant");
```

Comment: if post 1st data "mid_merchant": [
      "112000902755",
      "112000902754"
    ],

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code

```
JSONArray arrMid=json.getJSONArray("mid_merchant");
String mid=arrMid.getJSONOBJECT.getJSONObject(0).getString("mid_merchant");

JSONArray tidMid=json.getJSONArray("tid_merchant");
String mid=tidMid.getJSONOBJECT.getJSONObject(0).getString("tid_merchant");
```